# Use AWK to print FILENAME to CSV

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, cat

I have a little script to compare some columns inside a bunch of CSV files. 
It's working fine, but there are some things that are bugging me.

Here is the code:

```
FILES=./*
for f in $FILES

do
    cat -v $f | sed "s/\^A/,/g" > op_tmp.csv
    awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR == 1{next} $9=="T"{t[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="A"{a[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="C"{c[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="R"{r[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="P"{p[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} END{ for (i in n){print i "|" "A" "|" a[i]; print i "|" "C" "|" c[i]; print i "|" "R" "|" r[i]; print i "|" "P" "|" p[i]; print i "|" "T" "|" t[i] "|" (t[i]==a[i]+c[i]+r[i]+p[i] ? "ERROR" : "MATCHED")} }' op_tmp.csv >> output.csv
    rm op_tmp.csv
done
```

Just to explain:
I get all files on the directory, then i use CAT to replace the divisor ^A for a Pipe |. 
Then i use the awk onliner to compare the columns i need and print the result to a output.csv.

But now i want to print the filename before every loop.
I tried using the cat sed and awk in the same line and printing the $FILENAME, but it doesn't work:

```
cat -v $f | sed "s/\^A/,/g" | awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR == 1{next} $9=="T"{t[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="A"{a[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="C"{c[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="R"{r[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} $9=="P"{p[$8]+=$7;n[$8]} END{ for (i in n){print i "|" "A" "|" a[i]; print i "|" "C" "|" c[i]; print i "|" "R" "|" r[i]; print i "|" "P" "|" p[i]; print i "|" "T" "|" t[i] "|" (t[i]==a[i]+c[i]+r[i]+p[i] ? "ERROR" : "MATCHED")} }' > output.csv
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the whole script better, but assuming it does what you want for now just add

`echo $f >> output.csv`

before awk call.

If you want to add filename in every awk output line, you have to pass it as an argument, i.e.

```
 awk ... -v fname="$f" '{...; print fname... etc
```

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite:

```
for f in ./*; do
    awk -F '\x01' -v OFS="|" '
        BEGIN { 
            letter[1]="A"; letter[2]="C"; letter[3]="R"; letter[4]="P"; letter[5]="T" 
            letters["A"] = letters["C"] = letters["R"] = letters["P"] = letters["T"] = 1
        }
        NR == 1 {next} 
        $9 in letters {
            count[$9,$8] += $7
            seen[$8]
        }
        END { 
            print FILENAME
            for (i in seen) {
                sum = 0
                for (j=1; j<=4; j++) {
                    print i, letter[j], count[letter[j],i]
                    sum += count[letter[j],i]
                }
                print i, "T", count["T",i], (count["T",i] == sum ? "ERROR" : "MATCHED")
            } 
        }
    ' "$f"
done > output.csv
```

Notes:

- your method of iterating over files will break as soon as you have a filename with a space in it
- try to reduce duplication as much as possible.
- newlines are free, use them to improve readability
- improve your variable names `i`, `n`, etc -- here "letter" and "letters" could use improvement to hold some *meaning* about those symbols.
- awk has a `FILENAME` variable (*here's the actual answer to your question*)
- awk understands `\x01` to be a Ctrl-A -- I assume that's the field separator in your input files
- define an Output Field Separator that you'll actually use

If you have GNU awk (version ???) you can use the `ENDFILE` block and do away with the shell `for` loop altogether:

```
gawk -F '\x01' -v OFS="|" '
    BEGIN {...}
    FNR == 1 {next}
    $9 in letters {...}
    ENDFILE {
        print FILENAME
        for ...
        # clean up the counters for the next file
        delete count
        delete seen
    }
' ./* > output.csv
```

Comment: Even without gawk you could, along with a couple of other tweaks, put that END block in a function and call it in `FNR==1` and `END` conditions and you wouldn't need a shell loop. `ENDFILE` showed up in gawk 4.0 btw, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Feature-History.

Comment: That rewrite worked, eventually i will update to something like that, but right now i just adjusted using a variable $fname and printing before each loop. Also removed the temporary file and the cat. Thank you a lot.